# Calculate percent in spotfire cross table

Tags: pivot-table, crosstab, spotfire

I have a cross table where a person has a set of tasks and if the person has completed the task or not.  I want to be able to add another column to the cross table that calculates the percent of tasks completed (Yes/Grand total).  Is this possible?

Here's an image of the cross table:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Insert the below expression on your `VALUE AXIS` where `[ValueColumn]` is what ever column is giving you the values for YES and NO. If it's just a Count of the rows, i.e. `COUNT()` or if you are counting a non-integer column, you'll use `Count()` or `UniqueCount()` in place of `Sum([ValueColumn])`

```
Sum([ValueColumn]) THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Rows]))
```